# Nuxt js website doesn't works in other countries

Tags: nginx, vue.js, proxy, config, nuxt.js

I have [website](http://allhospital.info), which written with nuxt js. it doesn't works in other countries. here screenshot result of testing website in different countries. [image](http://joxi.ru/4Ak4YZoTy4xqGr)
it my nginx config:

```
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
"text/html"                 epoch;
"text/html; charset=utf-8"  epoch;
default                     off;
}

server { 
  server_name www.allhospital.info; return 301 
  $scheme://allhospital.info$request_uri; 
}
server {
 listen          80;             
 server_name     allhospital.info www.allhospital.info;

gzip            on;
gzip_types      text/plain application/xml text/css 
application/javascript;
gzip_min_length 1000;

# Useful logs for debug.
access_log      /var/log/nginx/allhospital_info.log;
error_log       /var/log/nginx/allhospital_info_error.log;

location / {

    expires $expires;

    #auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    #auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    proxy_redirect                      off;
    proxy_set_header Host               $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    proxy_read_timeout          1m;
    proxy_connect_timeout       1m;
    proxy_pass                          http://localhost:9000;

  }
 }
```

Comment: It's working from the United States. What country are you trying to view from?

Comment: It works in Sweden too. I'm like 99% sure your problem isnt based on what country you view it in, unless e.g. you have internationalization that gets messed up because of improper handling of various language codes.

Comment: the problem was because of nuxt js. develop incorrectly identified local language.